# Failed Outbound Messages not being retried

Tags: soap-api, integration, workflowoutboundmessage

We are using workflow rules and outbound messages to synchronize updates to Salesforce data with an external database.  I believe that this was working at one time, but I recently discovered that failing messages are not being retried, and I'm trying to track this down and fix it.  Specifically, I've configured my PHP outbound message processor to intentionally fail ALL messages, just for testing.  I have confirmed that Salesforce's Outbound Message web request is receiving the following SOAP reply:

```xml
HTTP/1.1 500 forcing failure for testing
Date: Tue, 12 May 2020 22:00:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 300
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:notificationsResponse><ns1:Ack>false</ns1:Ack></ns1:notificationsResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I've seen some sample XML responses posted that are slightly different than this but:

1. this is what the PHP SoapServer class is generating as defined by the WSDL, and I'd prefer to use that rather than generating a custom response by hand, and
2. I think the namespace definitions, while different, are equivalent.

I also feel like any HTTP status code of 500 should be considered an error by Salesforce, but I included a full SOAP response anyway just in case that made any difference.  I've also tried using 400 HTTP status codes with the same result.

I've confirmed that I've got current WSDL for the outbound message.  I can see the outbound message in the queue when it gets sent, but it appears to just "go away" after that.

I'm kind of at my wit's end here because I can't understand why that response is apparently being taken as a successful result.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have your verified that your outbound messages are hitting the expected endpoint? I'd be surprised if a 500 error response or a NACK would result in the message leaving the outbound message queue.

Comment: @DanielBallinger The response I showed above is a response to an outbound message, and the endpoint's logging and the Apache access logs confirm that the messages are being received.  I'm equally surprised that a 500 error response could be considered a successful delivery.